# How to find the minimum value of a group when certain value subjected to a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of subjects that participate in several races of different  lengths and I have calculate the run speed per km in order to find the best race lengths for each particular subjects ( that has the fastest run speed per km)

In addition, I would like to create the following variables:
“best_run_speed_1000”, “best_run_speed_1200” best_run_speed_1650, best_run_speed_1800,  best_run_speed_2200, best_run_speed_1400, best_run_speed_1600, best_run_speed_2000, best_run_speed_2400,

and have them updated after each race. I have created another variable best_run_speed which contains the race distance in meters, when the above variables has the minimum value after it has updated after each race.

I have tried the following code.

```
df["best_distance_1200"]= df.sort_values(["raceid"], ascending= True).groupby(["horseid"],)["run_speed_per_km"].transform('min').eq(df.run_speed_per_km) & df["distance-1"].eq("1200")
```

It should look something like this..

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp1T1.png]

The data is sorted according to the racedate and grouped by each subject, so the best_run_speed_1200 column should be carried over to the second race for  subject A, to allow comparision for all the previous races by subject A for best_speed. The same thing happens for subject B in best_run_speed_1650 column. The best_speed will be updated using the current_speed if the current_speed is smaller than the  best_speed in the previous row, to ensure that we have the best_speed at each race distance we have seen so far- after each races( at each row). Otherwise, if the current_speed is larger than the best_speed, the best_speed in the previous row will be carried over.
Finally, the best_distance for subject C at the end of the second race should be 1400m instead of 1600m.

The sample data is as follows:

```
 data = {
'racedate':['1/1/2024', '2/1/2024', '5/1/2024', '8/1/2024', '4/1/2024', '9/1/2024'], 
    'subject_id': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'race_distance': [1000, 1200, 1650, 1800, 1400, 1600],
    'race_time': [5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 7.5] 
}
 

The expected result should be like this:
 
  subject_id  race_distance  race_time  race_time_hours  speed_per_km  \
0          A           1000        5.0         0.083333        12.000   
1          A           1200        6.0         0.100000        12.000   
2          B           1650        8.0         0.133333        12.375   
3          B           1800        9.0         0.150000        12.000   
4          C           1400        7.0         0.116667        12.000   
5          C           1600        7.5         0.125000        12.800   

   best_run_speed_1000  best_run_speed_1200  best_run_speed_1650  \
0                 12.0                  NaN                  NaN   
1                 12.0                 12.0                  NaN   
2                  NaN                  NaN               12.375   
3                  NaN                  NaN               12.375   
4                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
5                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   

   best_run_speed_1800  best_run_speed_2200  best_run_speed_1400  \
0                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
1                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
3                 12.0                  NaN                  NaN   
4                  NaN                  NaN                 12.0   
5                  NaN                  NaN                 12.0   

  best_run_speed_1600  best_run_speed_2000  best_run_speed_2400  \
0                 NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
1                 NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
2                 NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
3                 NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
4                 NAN                  NaN                  NaN   
5                12.8                  NaN                  NaN   

   best_run_speed  best_run_distance  
0          12.000             1000.0  
1          12.000             1200.0  
2          12.375             1650.0  
3          12.000             1800.0  
4          12.000             1400.0  
5          12.000             1400.0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide the code that you've worked on so far, so users have a better idea of what you're having issues with. Refrain from sharing the data as an image and share a small reproducible example instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Your requirements would be a lot clearer if you provide a minimal example of the initial data and the expected results from that data. Your code is not clear. Ideally provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

For the future, do follow the comments posted above. Do not past images.

Now, for you problem. What you need to do is begin by calculateing the distances that each subject has run. Once you've done that you need to update the best run speeds for all specific distances. Those two pieces of information then allow you to find the overall best run speed and distance. To do this, i created the functions `update_best_speeds` and  `find_overall_best` and applied them to a fictive dataframe. You might have to modify both the functions and the implementation (whereof the need to join a minimal representative example of your data to your question.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'subject_id': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'race_distance': [1000, 1200, 1650, 1800, 1400, 1600],
    'race_time': [5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 7.5] 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['race_time_hours'] = df['race_time'] / 60
df['speed_per_km'] = df['race_distance'] / 1000 / df['race_time_hours']

specific_distances = [1000, 1200, 1650, 1800, 2200, 1400, 1600, 2000, 2400]

for distance in specific_distances:
    df[f'best_run_speed_{distance}'] = np.nan

def update_best_speeds(row, specific_distances):
    for distance in specific_distances:
        if row['race_distance'] == distance:
            current_speed = row['speed_per_km']
            if pd.isna(row[f'best_run_speed_{distance}']) or current_speed > row[f'best_run_speed_{distance}']:
                row[f'best_run_speed_{distance}'] = current_speed
    return row

df = df.apply(lambda row: update_best_speeds(row, specific_distances), axis=1)

def find_overall_best(row, specific_distances):
    best_speed = 0
    best_distance = None
    for distance in specific_distances:
        if not pd.isna(row[f'best_run_speed_{distance}']) and row[f'best_run_speed_{distance}'] > best_speed:
            best_speed = row[f'best_run_speed_{distance}']
            best_distance = distance
    return pd.Series([best_speed, best_distance], index=['best_run_speed', 'best_run_distance'])

df[['best_run_speed', 'best_run_distance']] = df.apply(lambda row: find_overall_best(row, specific_distances), axis=1)
print(df)
```

which returns

```
  subject_id  race_distance  race_time  race_time_hours  speed_per_km  \
0          A           1000        5.0         0.083333        12.000   
1          A           1200        6.0         0.100000        12.000   
2          B           1650        8.0         0.133333        12.375   
3          B           1800        9.0         0.150000        12.000   
4          C           1400        7.0         0.116667        12.000   
5          C           1600        7.5         0.125000        12.800   

   best_run_speed_1000  best_run_speed_1200  best_run_speed_1650  \
0                 12.0                  NaN                  NaN   
1                  NaN                 12.0                  NaN   
2                  NaN                  NaN               12.375   
3                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
4                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
5                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN   
...
2          12.375             1650.0  
3          12.000             1800.0  
4          12.000             1400.0  
5          12.800             1600.0
```

#UPDATE

Since it is the cumulative best time you are looking for, you can modify the answer I gave above this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'subject_id': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'race_distance': [1000, 1200, 1650, 1800, 1400, 1600],
    'race_time': [5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 7.5] 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['race_time_hours'] = df['race_time'] / 60
df['speed_per_km'] = df['race_distance'] / 1000 / df['race_time_hours']

specific_distances = [1000, 1200, 1650, 1800, 2200, 1400, 1600, 2000, 2400]

cumulative_best_times = {subject: {distance: np.inf for distance in specific_distances} for subject in df['subject_id'].unique()}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    subject = row['subject_id']
    distance = row['race_distance']
    time = row['race_time']
    if time < cumulative_best_times[subject][distance]:
        cumulative_best_times[subject][distance] = time

best_distances = {}
for subject, distances in cumulative_best_times.items():
    best_distance = min(distances, key=distances.get)
    best_distances[subject] = best_distance

df['best_distance'] = df['subject_id'].map(best_distances)

print(df)
```

which adds the column `best_distance` to the dataframe. It gives the best distance for each subject based on cumulative best times. Each row shosw the best distance for the subject who participated in that race.

```
subject_id  race_distance  race_time  race_time_hours  speed_per_km  \
0          A           1000        5.0         0.083333        12.000   
1          A           1200        6.0         0.100000        12.000   
2          B           1650        8.0         0.133333        12.375   
3          B           1800        9.0         0.150000        12.000   
4          C           1400        7.0         0.116667        12.000   
5          C           1600        7.5         0.125000        12.800   

   best_distance  
0           1000  
1           1000  
2           1650  
3           1650  
4           1400  
5           1400
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm sorry that my question is not clear-
I would like to find the cumulative best time for each distance for each subject, the minimum of which is the best distance for subject A at that time.   
I have put the expected result in the edit section. Thank you.